# Eloquent ORM Movie Location

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4 and eloquent orm to build a movie session database.

Now I have the following Models.

```
class Location extends \Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = 'movsys_location';
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'desc');

    public function sessions(){
        return $this->hasMany('Session', 'location_id');
    }
}


class Session extends \Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = 'movsys_session';
    protected $fillable = array('time');

    public function location(){
        return $this->hasOne('Location', 'id');
    }
}
```

(Note: These models are stripped to the necessary code.)

Now in my controller, I have the following.

```
$Sessions = Session::all();
foreach($Sessions as $Session){
    echo (isset($Session->location->name) ? $Session->location->name : 'NO LOCATION');
}
```

And this is what my database looks like: 
[image: 'Sessions']
[image: 'Locations']

Now, everything seems to work, but even though both sessions have the same location, ONLY the first session will return the name of the location! The second echo will return "NO LOCATION".

Any idea or help as to why would be appreciated. If this answer isnt clear enough let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in place of yours:

```
class Session extends \Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = 'movsys_session';
    protected $fillable = array('time');

    public function location(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Location');
    }
}
```